# Simple paragraph formatting of strings in mvc 4 or 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, string-formatting

I'm using MVC 4 I have a string being stored in SQL Server as varchar(Max) my data annotations in the model specify DataType(DataType.MultilineText). I would think that the helpers for displaying this type of text would not just spit it all out on one line, but none of the formatting from the multiline text box is coming through when I display it on a page using the basic scaffolding. But the formatting does show up when I go to edit that description on the crud side. Why is this so hard to do out of the box. I can use a MVC 4 or 5 solution. I would think they would be similar.

I use the following methods to display on my page:

```
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InstructionEn)
```

&

```
    @recipe.RecipeInstructionsEn
```

I'm thinking something that will replace New lines with 
 tags might work. But how would I go about that? I know the New line formatting is there.

I also thought about using markdown, but wouldn't know where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to replace the plain text newline character (`\n`) with the HTML one (`<br />`):

```
@Html.Raw(recipe.RecipeInstructionsEn.Replace("\n", "<br />"))
```

The use of `Html.Raw` prevents the default HTML encoding that Razor applies. Without it, the newline entity will display as "<br />" instead of acting as an HTML line break.

Comment: I had used Html.Raw, but not with the replace. I often know where to go to find things out but sometimes I miss the exact implementation. I was really tired last night. Thanks. I'll see what I can do with this!

Comment: Perfect, I knew it was simple. I looked so many places for this and I found people instantiating entire classes to show how to replace /n with <br /> tags and put the value into a new variable and it just didn't make sense for a simple application of it.